# Why is my server saying "No such file or directory" error for a file that is clearly there

Tags: linux, gentoo

```
ritwik@indus ~/perforce $ ls
p4d
ritwik@indus ~/perforce $ ./p4d 
-bash: ./p4d: No such file or directory
```

You understood the problem right ? 
Why is this happening ? How do I fix it ?

```
ritwik@indus ~/p4 $ ls -q
p4d
ritwik@indus ~/p4 $ ls -b
p4d
```

Comment: What type of file is this? What are the permissions (ls -l)?

Comment: I did a `chmod a+x` on it before running it. `-rwxr-xr-x 1 ritwik ritwik 5690532 Oct 24 19:12 p4d`

Comment: show us the output of `ls -q` and/or `ls -b`.

Comment: ritwik@indus ~/p4 $ ls -q
p4d
ritwik@indus ~/p4 $ ls -b
p4d

Comment: What OS is this?

Comment: @ewwhite Gentoo.

Comment: Run `file p4d` and post the output.

Comment: Please also show the output of `ldd p4d`.

Answer (score 1):

If your binary was running on another system (a 32-bit system maybe?) and you have a 64-bit system you probably don't have the 32-bit support installed. Do you have a 64-bit version of the same software?

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system/13409#13409

Answer (score 0):

If this is a shell script, check the line endings on the file. If there are DOS line endings, it could be that the interpreter line isn't being understood.

```
dos2unix p4d
```

Comment: It is not a shell script. It is a binary. And it ran ok on one computer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have a space in the filename. What do you get it you run this?

```
find . -name *p4d* -exec echo \"{}\" \;
```

I'm guessing it'll be something like `"./p4d "` (note the space before the end quote). If this is the case, you can fix it by running

```
mv p4d* p4d
```

Comment: That could be interesting.

Comment: Normally I would suggest a more specific command to avoid clobbering multiple files, but we can already see that there's only  one file in the directory.

Comment: Nope. Thats not it. No spaces in the output of that command. Also, `ritwik@indus ~/perforce $ mv p4d* p4d
mv: ‘p4d’ and ‘p4d’ are the same file`

Comment: Does it find the file if you run `ls -l p4d`? If so, can you try executing the file using the full path instead of relative path?